# Array in for-loop (with jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

Im trying to get my Array Entires inside a jQuery-Code which is inside a for-loop.

```
var list = ["name1", "name2" ];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)

{

$('ul.list li a[href*=(ary[i])]').parent().hide();

}
```

Im stuck and need help, thanks in advance!

BTW: This code is for a Greasemonkey Userscript (Firefox).

```
$('ul.list li a[href*="name"]').parent().hide();
```

works just fine. But with a couple hundret "names" I dont want to repeat this line all the time like this

```
$('ul.list li a[href*="name1"]').parent().hide();
$('ul.list li a[href*="name2"]').parent().hide();
[...]
$('ul.list li a[href*="name492"]').parent().hide();
```

EDIT: To avoid misunderstanding, in action the array would be not ["name1, "name2"] but something random like ["red", "banana", "pacific"]

Comment: Do these typos exist in your live code? `list.lenght` should be `list.length`?  Do you get any errors in your javascript console?  `[href*=(ary[i])]` won't work = needs to be `[href="' + list[i] + '"]`

Comment: length in my live code yes. but thanks for the href correction. a[href*="' + list[i] + '"] works fine! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = ["name1", "name2" ];

$.each(list, function(index, name) {
    $('ul.list li a[href*="'+name+'"]').parent().hide();
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

A string literal is not evaluated for variable names. You need to concatenate the value with strings to use it that way:

```
$('ul.list li a[href*=' + list[i] + ']').parent().hide();
```

Comment: @cale_b: Thanks, didn't spot that.